# Set plotly tooltip background color the same as the hovered pixel of an image

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using Plotly to display an image (3 channels, not just a heatmap). I want to add custom information when I hover a pixel.

I managed to display the RGB values with `hovertemplate` and `customdata`, but I also would like to have the background color of the tooltip the same color as the hovered pixel.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

size = 5
img = np.random.random((size, size, 3)) * 255

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Image(
        z=img,
        customdata=img.astype(int),
        hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
            "R: %{customdata[0]}",
            "G: %{customdata[1]}",
            "B: %{customdata[2]}"
            ]),
        name=''
    )
)
fig.show('browser')
```

[image: Result so far]

Is there a way to set the background (or the text) color of the tooltip the same one as the hovered pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is converted to RGB color format using heatmap data, the background color of the hover label will be the same as the cell color.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(1)
size = 5
img = np.random.random((size, size, 3)) * 255

flat_list = ['rgb({},{},{})'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2]) for row in img.astype(int) for x in row]
colors_list = np.array(flat_list).reshape(5,5)

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Image(
        z=img,
        customdata=img.astype(int),
        hoverlabel=dict(
            bgcolor=colors_list
        ),
        hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
            "R: %{customdata[0]}",
            "G: %{customdata[1]}",
            "B: %{customdata[2]}"
            ]),
        name=''
    )
)
fig.show('browser')
```

[image]

Comment: Working like a charm! Maybe this version would be a bit better as it will create less intermediate arrays I think: `colors_list = np.reshape(['rgb({},{},{})'.format(*x) for x in img.reshape(-1, img.shape[-1])], img.shape[:2])`

Comment: I find the method of commenting even more concise.